# NullPointerException possibility in Integer.toString(arg) method in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, tostring

Is there any possibility that `Integer.toString(args)` give an `NullPointerException` like `String.valueOf(args)`.

I know its Silly Question  but I want to be clear that is there any possibility that `Integer.toString()` can give `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yes, `if` `args` is `null`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can't, `args` is of type `int`.

Comment: @Tunaki It could be an `Integer`, and auto-unboxing of a `null` is a NPE.

Comment: Presumably you have access to a java compiler.  Consider writing a short test to determine if Integer.toString(null) throws a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 5):

`Integer.toString(args)` may give an `NullPointerException` **un**like `String.valueOf(args)`.

```
Integer i = null; 
Integer.toString(i);        // Null pointer exception!! 
String.valueOf(i);          // No exception 
i.toString();               // Again, Null pointer exception!!
```

See my experiment here : http://rextester.com/YRGGY86170

Answer (score 3):

Technically yes, due to unboxing. Although I'm not sure if that is what you meant:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = null;
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(i)); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, it's not `toString` that's throwing the exception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: OP asked whether `Integer.toString(args)` can cause a NPE. Which is exactly what I showed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes and no. It depends on how one interprets your question.

Is it possible for the expression `var.toString()` (or `Integer.toString(var)`) to throw a NullPointerException?
**Yes.**

Can the method `Integer.toString()` (or `Integer.toString(int)`) ever throw a NullPointerException?
**No.**

In `var.toString()`, a NullPointerException will be thrown if `var` is null. But the exception will be thrown by the current method, and `toString()` will not be called.

In `Integer.toString(var)`, a NullPointerException will be thrown if `var` is null. But it is *not* the `toString(int)` method that throws it. If var is an Integer object, the expression is shorthand for

```
Integer.toString(var.intValue())
```

and so obviously if `var` is null, a NullPointerException will be thrown by the current method, and neither `intValue()` nor `toString(int)` will be called.

So to reiterate, `toString()` and `toString(int)` themselves never throw NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the static method `toString(int i)` of class `Integer`? That method will never throw `NullPointerException` - there is no `int` value that you can pass that will ever produce a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @IgnacioChiazzo how do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Integer#toString does not take any args, and only passes in the field `value`. `value` can never be null because you cannot pass a null `int` primitive and a null `String` will simply throw a `NumberFormatException` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#443)

EDIT:
I did not consider the toString methods which take an `int`, but the results will be the same - `int` can never be null so there will be no NPE